# Maxima: how to write repeating decimal?

Tags: math, symbolic-math, algebra, maxima

For example, I have `0.333...(=1/3)`. Have I  ways to write it without converting `0.333...` to `1/3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Maxima doesn't have a way to work with repeating decimals directly. You could construct infinite series e.g. `'sum(3/10^k, k, 1, inf)` although that might be kind of clumsy.